# what does “bank” mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Jamie Dimon said in interview at Stanford “ We bank 50 million people on out households and soon we are going to have online investing and robo investing” I am nkt sure if we bank 50 million households means that they lend money to 50 million households?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We **bank** 50 million people **on** out households and soon we are going to have online investing and robo investing”

We're usually tempted to make an assumption here since there's an 'investing' word, it might be related to some kind of 'bank transaction such as lending/borrowing/any transaction with bank or making account with bank' while in this context, it means  **to rely on confidently**, and with added context, it means that:

> We ***depend on*** 50 million people ***(out (of)/motivated by)*** households and soon we are going
>   to have online investing and robo investing
>
> **Bank on** here is a phrasal verbs. It means **to depend or rely on
>   confidently or to rely on a future occurrence (even though it might not happen)**.

[**Oxford Source**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bank)

[**Webster Source**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bank)

[**Cambridge Source**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/bank-on-someone-something)

[**Free Dictionary Source**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bank)